# Evaluate $\int \cos(3x) \sin(2x) \, dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

> Evaluate the indefinite integral 
>   \begin{align}
> \int \cos(3x) \sin(2x) \, dx
> \end{align}

Please see my work attempt as my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT:

Using [Werner Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html)

$$2\cos3x\sin2x=\sin(3x+2x)-\sin(3x-2x)$$

Now use $\displaystyle\int\sin mx\ dx=-\frac{\cos mx}m+C$

Finally and optionally, we can use [Multiple Angle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html) Formula to expand $\cos5x$ in the power of $\cos x$

Comment: @glacier, observe that this method is more generic & universal. For example, what is $$\int\cos\frac{5x}3\sin\frac{3x}2$$  Also, for each pair of $(m,n)$ in $$\int\cos mx\sin mx\ dx$$ deriving such calculation like yours can be really tough

Comment: The identities are often referred to as product-to-sum identities (at least in America).

Answer (score 4):

Write
$$\cos 3x \sin 2x =\left(\frac{e^{3ix}+e^{-3ix}}{2}\right)\left(\frac{e^{2ix}-e^{-2ix}}{2i}\right)=\frac{e^{5ix}-e^{ix}+e^{-ix}-e^{-5ix}}{2\cdot2i}$$
$$=\frac12 \left(\frac{e^{5ix}-e^{-5ix}}{2i}\right) - \frac12 \left(\frac{e^{ix}-e^{ix}}{2i}\right)=\frac12\sin 5x - \frac12\sin x$$
Then integrate to get
$$\int\cos 3x \sin 2x \; dx= \int\left(\frac12\sin 5x - \frac12\sin x\right)\;dx= \boxed{-\dfrac1{10}\cos 5x +\dfrac12\cos x + C}$$

Answer (score 3):

Employing trigonometric identities, we have
\begin{align}
\int \cos3x \sin2x \, dx &= \int \cos(2x+x) \sin2x \, dx \\
&= \int [\cos2x\cos x  - \sin2x\sin x ]\sin2x \, dx \\
&= \int \cos2x \cos x  \sin2x - \sin^2 2x \sin x  \, dx \\
&= \int (\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x) \cos x (2 \sin x \cos x) - (2 \sin x \cos x)^2 \sin x \, dx \\
&= \int 2 \cos^4 x \sin x - 2 \cos^2 x \sin^3 x - 4 \sin^3 x \cos^2 x \, dx \\
&= \int 2 \cos^4 x \sin x - 6 \sin^3 x \cos^2 x \, dx \\
&= \int 2 \cos^4 x \sin x \, dx - \int 6 \sin^3 x \cos^2 x \, dx \\
\end{align}

For the first term, we invoke the substitution rule by letting $u = \cos x$. Then $du = -\sin x \, dx$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\int 2 \cos^4 x \sin x \, dx &= \int 2u^4 (-du) \\
&= -\frac{2}{5}u^5 + C \\
&= -\frac{2}{5} \cos^5 x + C
\end{align}

Similarly for the second term, let $v = \cos(x)$. Then $dv = -\sin(x) \, dx$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\int 6 \sin^3 x \cos^2 x \, dx &= \int 6 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x \sin x \, dx \\
&= \int 6 (1 - \cos^2 x) \cos^2 x \sin x \, dx \\
&= \int 6 (1-v^2)v^2 (-dv) \\
&= \int -6v^2 + 6v^4 dv \\
&= -2v^3 + \frac{6}{5}v^5 + C \\
&= -2 \cos^3 x + \frac{6}{5} \cos^5 x + C
\end{align}

Combining the two terms together, we get
\begin{align}
\int \cos 3x \sin 2x \, dx &= \left(-\frac{2}{5} \cos^5 x + C\right) - \left(-2 \cos^3 x + \frac{6}{5} \cos^5 x + C \right) \\
&= -\frac 85 \cos^5 x + 2 \cos^3 x + C
\end{align}

Comment: Hmm, looking back at this, I'm not sure if I have the right antiderivative...